# How to define a large number of resources that use the same logic without creating boilerplate modules in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a large number of resources that use exactly the same logic. Each resource has a `<resource>` route and a `<resource>.show` route. I've defined `BaseRoute`, `BaseShowRoute`, `BaseController`, `BaseShowController` and corresponding templates to capture this common logic. I set the appropriate controller/templates on the route objects:

```
// routes/base.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'base',
  templateName: 'base'
});

// routes/base/show.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'baseShow',
  templateName: 'baseShow'
});
```

But in order to use these route prototypes with my resources, I have to have two modules for each resource:

```
// routes/<resource>.js
import BaseRoute from './base';

export default BaseRoute.extend({
});


// routes/<resource>/show.js
import BaseShowRoute from './base/show'

export default BaseShowRoute.extend({
});
```

This seems silly. I would like to specify that all of these resources should use `BaseRoute` and `BaseShowRoute` without needing to create these modules. It would be reasonable to have this option in `Router.map`. Something like this:

```
Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('articles', { extends: BaseRoute }, function() {
      this.route('show', { path: ':article_id', extends: BaseShowRoute })
    });
});
```

But to my knowledge there is nothing like the `extends` option I'm using above.

The only documentation I can find for the `route` and `resource` methods invoked in `Router.map` is in the [Routing Guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/). The only option that you can pass to these methods seems to be `path`.  The ember-cli user guide does say that you can override the base class for all generated routes if you define routes/basic.js, but this is not enough for me-- I need multiple base classes.

How can I get rid of my boilerplate route modules?

Answer (score 0):

In our application we have exactly the same usecase as you. As far as I know there isn't such API in `Router`. The boilerplate is needed only for routes, so the controller module is not needed and we define it the same way as you do:

```
// routes/base/show.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'baseShow',
});
```

The problem is that Ember picks the same instance of Controller for every resources. That is ok for most of our resources, but some need their own state (for example: the form has more than one tab and we want to remember the last active tab for each resource) and then we define the controller and override `controllerName`:

```
// routes/user/show.js
import BaseShowRoute from './base/show'

export default BaseShowRoute.extend({
    controllerName: 'user/show',
});
```

It would be great if `Route` had a property `controllerClass` telling Ember: Create instance of this `Controller` for this `Route`.

Comment: Hmm, good to see someone else has similar issues. I'm not crazy! This seems like an oversight by the ember-cli team. It is likely fairly common to want to use the same logic for different resources and ember-cli really makes this unnecessarily difficult. Since this SO question hasn't received much love, I'll put some more thought into this and make a post on the Ember discourse forum.